# Android выход за экран

Tags: java, android

Как двигать область, если не помещается на экране?
Какая команда или опция отвечает за перемещение экрана?
К примеру: наставили на экране много элементов и они вышли за экран, как сделать сдвиг?

Есть класс `Viwer`, унаследованный от `ScrollView`, создаю `main.xml` и пишу там:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Viwer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/viwer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Дальше в `MainActivity`, пишу:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   super.setContentView(R.layout.main);
   final Viver viwer= findViewById(R.id.viwer);
   //... тут добавляется кучи объектов....
}
```

Все работает, за исключением, перемещения по области, то есть объекты вышедшие за экран, никак нельзя смотреть...

Comment: Вы имеете в виду возможность перемещать контент на экране жестами? Попробуйте ScrollView для этого

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я попробовал унаследоваться от `ScrollView` но ничего не удалось...

Comment: Наследоваться, по идее, и не нужно. Смолдно вам что-то конкретное сказать без кода, разметки, показа экрана и показа того, как оно должно выглядеть. Пока что можно сказать лишь, что ваша проблема элементарна и решается за минуту или очень сложна и решаема за приемлемое время только очень опытным специалистом. Скорее всего 1 вариант, но нет деталей для точного ответа.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Я не знаю, нужны ли вам такие подробности. но тут объяснять нечего. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Вам не надо наследовать ScrollView. Поместите в разметку обычный ScrollView, В него поместите LinearLayout с вертикальной ориентацией и именно в него добавляйте ваши вьюхи. Это будет работать в смысле вертикальной прокрутки. Горизонтальной не будет. Можно сделать наоборот - и прокрутка будет горизонтальной. И то и то сразу - очень сложно. За много лет не видел ни одного приемлемого решения. Вы всё не говорите что у вас конкретно не так, засим нельзя сказать конкретнее. Совсем не понятно что такое "Перемещаение по области". Такого термина в Android я не слышал.

Comment: Как в играх. камера бегает, за нами, когда перемещаем пальцами, вот мне нужно также, я просто не знаю как объяснить, я сам найти не могу как это называется правильно

Comment: Значит, вроде, у вас как раз таки сложный случай. Я пытался найти решение этой проблемы несколько лет назад и так её и не нашёл. У меня сложилось впечатление, что стандартного решения нет. Засим надо или самостоятельно писать очень сложный и объёмный код или использовать к-л игровой движок, в которых эта функционльность есть.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а сложный код, писать используя. что или хотябы с чего начать? Есть ли какие-то отдельные требования или заметки, куда копать? не хочется использовать движки готовые... Хотя, может посоветуете движек, где используется Java? А то например Unity там C#. не долюбливаю его.

Comment: Так глубоко я не копал. Возможно, получится переопределять ScrollView и в нём долго возиться с обработками тача и скрола. Под Java, вроде, OpenGL можно взять. Но надо учитывать, что вам, возможно это таки и не нужно. Если вы, конечно, не игру делаете.

Answer (score 0):

Выделите в ComponentTree то, что нужно вывести из скрытой области, и нажмите 
**Senter->Vertically** или **Senter->Horizontally**